# How to output an array that has nested arrays in Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

I'm creating a basic concept of a music player using Pascal, but I'm struggling to display the albums inside it. The error I got says "(134, 29) Error: Can't read or write variables of this type". I'm assuming it's saying that because I'm using an array within an array, and it's having a hard time displaying both at the same time (although I only want it to display the albums, not the tracks as well).

Here's what my code looks like:

```
function ReadAllTrack(prompt: String): Tracks;
var
    i: Integer;
    trackArray: Array of Track;
    trackCount: Integer;
begin
    WriteLn(prompt);
    trackCount := ReadIntegerGreaterThan1('Please enter the number of tracks you would like to add: ');
    Setlength(trackArray, trackCount);
    for i := 0 to trackCount - 1 do
    begin
        WriteLn('Enter the details for your track:');    
        trackArray[i] := ReadTrack();
    end;
    result := trackArray;
end;

function ReadAlbum(): Album;
begin
    result.albumName := ReadString('Album name: ');
    result.artistName := ReadString('Artist name: ');
    result.albumGenre := ReadGenre('Genre:');
    result.trackCollection := ReadAllTrack('Track Collection:');
end;

function ReadAllAlbums(): Albums;
var
    i: Integer;
    albumArray: Array of Album;
    albumCount: Integer;
begin
    albumCount := ReadIntegerGreaterThan1('Please enter the number of albums you would like to add: ');
    Setlength(albumArray, albumCount);
    for i := 0 to albumCount - 1 do
    begin
        WriteLn('Enter the details for your album:');
        albumArray[i] := ReadAlbum();
    end;
    result := albumArray;
end;

procedure DisplayAlbumOptions(listOfAllAlbums: Albums);
var
    userInput: Integer;
begin
    WriteLn('1. Display all albums');
    WriteLn('2. Display all albums for a genre');
    userInput := ReadIntegerRange('Please enter a number (1, 2) to select: ', 1, 2);

    case userInput of
        1: WriteLn(listOfAllAlbums); //Error: Can't read or write variables of this type
    end;
end;
```

Basically what this does is it will ask the user showing 5 options:
1. Add albums
2. Display albums
etc

If the user selects 1, the program will ask the user to input the number of albums they want to input. Then for each album it'll ask them to enter the details, and then the tracks.

Then if the user selects 2, the program will ask the user to choose either display every single album there is, or display all albums for a single genre (I'll be working on this one after solving this problem). At first I thought it would be just as simple as `WriteLn(TheAlbumArray);` but turns out it was more complicated than I thought because I don't think it's possible for the program to display it this way. I tried separating the albums and tracks so that it would only display the albums when I use `WriteLn(TheAlbumArray);` but it wasn't possible because the tracks still have to be "inside" the album so that when I display the albums and select one of them, it would then display the tracks....

Any help or suggestion for this and/or the second will be much appreciated ^^

Comment: Can you cut this down to a minimal example and point out the line of code that fails. This should be possible in no more than 20 lines of code.

Comment: Ok I've tried cutting it down, hope that helped a little bit.

Comment: Well, now we don't know what the types ares. We don't need all the input and so on. Surely all we need is an array and your call to Writeln. Anyway, you can't pass an array to Writeln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question contained a lot of superfluous detail. After the edit, you removed the type declarations, but kept much of the superfluous detail.

However, it is possible to discern the problem you are passing an array of record to `Writeln`. The `Writeln` function can accept only certain simple types as arguments, e.g. strings, numerical types, boolean. You certainly cannot pass an array to `Writeln`. You must iterate over the array and process each member individually.

So you might try

```
for i := low(listOfAllAlbums) to high(listOfAllAlbums) do
  WriteLn(listOfAllAlbums[i]);
```

But that does not work either, because `listOfAllAlbums[i]` is a record, and a record is a compound type which cannot be passed to `Writeln`. So you need to process the record separately. If you want to display just the title, then you write:

```
for i := low(listOfAllAlbums) to high(listOfAllAlbums) do
  WriteLn(listOfAllAlbums[i].albumName);
```

If you want to print the track titles too then you need to iterate over the array contained in the record.

```
for i := low(listOfAllAlbums) to high(listOfAllAlbums) do
begin
  WriteLn(listOfAllAlbums[i].albumName);
  for j := low(trackCollection) to high(trackCollection) do
    WriteLn(listOfAllAlbums[i].trackCollection[j]);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked for me perfectly. I'll also try to learn what bits to keep and what bits to cut the next time I paste my code in...

Comment: Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use composite types (arrays, records, ...) in `Read[ln]` and `Write[ln]` procedures.

To make your code more transparent you could to create type helper for your array(s) and use well-known `AsString` property. Here is example for simple `array of Integer`:

```
program foo;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$modeswitch typehelpers}

uses
    Classes, SysUtils;

type
    TMyArray = array of Integer;

    TMyArrayHelper = type helper for TMyArray
    private
        function GetAsString: string;
        procedure SetAsString(const AValue: string);
    public
        property AsString: string read GetAsString write SetAsString;
    end;

function TMyArrayHelper.GetAsString: string;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    for i in Self do
    begin
        if Result <> '' then
            Result := Result + ', ';
        Result := Result + IntToStr(i);
    end;
    Result := '[' + Result + ']';
end;

// Relatively simple parser
// Fill free to implement ones for your array type
procedure TMyArrayHelper.SetAsString(const AValue: string);
var
    tmp, s: string;
    items: TStringArray;
    i: Integer;
begin
    tmp := Trim(AValue);
    if not (tmp.StartsWith('[') and tmp.EndsWith(']')) then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid array literal format: "%s"', [tmp]);
    tmp := tmp.Trim(['[', ']']);
    items := tmp.Split([',']);
    for s in items do
        try
            StrToInt(s);
        except
            on e: Exception do
                raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid integer literal: "%s"', [s]);
        end;
    SetLength(Self, Length(items));
    for i := 0 to Length(items) - 1 do
        Self[i] := StrToInt(items[i]);
end;

var
    a1, a2: TMyArray;
begin
    a1.AsString := '[1,2,3,5]';
    Writeln('a1 = ', a1.AsString);
    a2.AsString := a1.AsString;
    a2[1] := 999;
    Writeln('a2 = ', a2.AsString);
end.
```

- [Helper types in FreePascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Helper_types)
- [TStringHelper in SysUtils unit](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/tstringhelper.html)